# Binary Tree - Inserting into a Non-Empty Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm trying to create a binary tree and I'm having trouble with the following code and getting error:

```
expression must have pointer-to-class type.
```

I'm getting the error with "tree" within insert(***tree***->left, value) and insert(***tree***->right, value);

```
void insert(node **tree, int value){
if (*tree == nullptr){
    *tree = new node;
    (*tree)->data = value;
    (*tree)->left = nullptr;
    (*tree)->right = nullptr;
}

else 
    if (value < (*tree)->data)
        insert(tree->left, value);  

    else if (value >(*tree)->data)
        insert(tree->right, value);

else
    return;
```

}

Comment: Alternatively, pass tree as a reference to pointer and save yourself a lot of '*' characters.

Comment: Thanks, that solved that issue but now I'm getting another error "IntelliSense: argument of type "node *" is incompatible with parameter of type "node **"

Comment: Would it be helpful to post the entire binary tree code?

Comment: Generally using this amount of pointers in C++ code is frowned upon, and hints that the design of the tree classes/interfaces is not ideal. If you want us to look at your entire binary tree code, I suggest posting it in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `node::left` and `node::right` are of type `node*`, you need to call insert as follows:

```
insert(&(*tree)->left, value);
```

Alternatively, pass tree as a pointer reference and save yourself a bunch of explicit dereferences:

```
void insert(node *&tree, int value){
    if (tree == nullptr){
        tree = new node;
        tree->data = value;
        tree->left = nullptr;
        tree->right = nullptr;
    }
    else if (value < tree->data)
        insert(tree->left, value);  
    else if (value > tree->data)
        insert(tree->right, value);
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks zennehoy, that did the trick, I went with the first option.